ehcache 3 with spring 6
I try the solution given in Using ehcache3 with Spring4
in my project with spring 6 and ehcache 3 and jdk17
 <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="cacheManagerUri" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
 </bean>

but I have this error. I dont understand why it search a javax. knowning that I have the lib jakarta.xml.bind-api in the pom
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler
    at org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:92)
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider$ConfigSupplier.getConfiguration(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:328)
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:134)
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider.getCacheManager(EhcacheCachingProvider.java:85)
    at org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)


It resolved by adding classifier :
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <version>3.10.8</version>
        </dependency>

